# How Do I Save Data in a Java Windows App?

Tags: java, windows, save

I'm creating a simple windows App using Java that allows users to save passwords and usernames from the websites of their choice. How do I make it so when the user logs off the app, the information the user posted in the app was saved? All of the data is being saved to arrays and linked lists, if that helps.

edit: I know about I/O and saving data to files. I'm looking for another solution if possible.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! There are many ways to achieve this. You could save to a file, for starters. Are you familiar with file I/O in Java? Note: You're probably going to attract downvotes on this, because it seems like you haven't done much searching or research. You'll get more positive attention if you mentioned what you have tried so far, and add more details about what you are trying to achieve. Otherwise, it's a vague question. Cheers!

Comment: The only thing I've tried so far is saving the information to a text file, which works well, but I was wondering if there was a better way to accomplish it. Something that's be more secure. All the solutions I found suggested a simple text file.

Answer (score 0):

Websites usernames and passwords should never be saved in any app or in machine.
It's not secure.

In response to your comment:-

Once the user go offline, you need to store the username and passwords.
So for this, you need a database where data will persist, and will be available when user login next time.
But store the data in encrypted format as it is highly sensitive.
You can explore [H2 database engine](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html), which is a in-memory database and do support encryption.

Comment: Assuming that this is something that I did for fun/experience, how would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You can write/read the objects as a file. Using Java IO. You just need to implement the Serializable class

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class DataToSend implements Serializable {

public ArrayList values = new ArrayList<Double>();

public DataToSend(ArrayList<Double> values){
    this.values = values;
}

public DataToSend() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public void addRandomValues(){
    for(int i=0;i<1001;i++){
        values.add(Math.random());
    }
}
}


import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Tester {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    try {           
        ObjectInputStream objIn = new ObjectInputStream(
                new   FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\*user*\\rotationValues"));

            ArrayList x = (ArrayList) objIn.readObject();
            System.out.println(x.toString());

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }

}
```